# javac cannot find symbol constructor Service

Tags: java, ant, jax-ws, cxf, endorsed

I am in the process of learning CXF with the help of this [Apache CXF Web Service Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847195407) book but, alas, one of the book's sample projects won't even compile!

The code in question is Chapter 3's `contractfirst` and it's not a typo problem because I am using the source code verbatim as downloaded from [the book's support site](http://www.packtpub.com/support/4096).

The 3 compilation errors point actually to a single problem:

```
Chapter3\contractfirst\src\demo\order\OrderProcessService.java:52: cannot find symbol
symbol: constructor Service(java.net.URL,javax.xml.namespace.QName,javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature[])
location: class javax.xml.ws.Service
super(WSDL_LOCATION, SERVICE, features);
^
```

In the file OrderProcessService.java.

Initial re[search](http://goo.gl/ccfLa) suggests that this may be a [JAX-WS 2.2 vs. 2.1](http://www.weston-fl.com/blog/?p=1673) issue but I have no idea how to make this ANT-based compilation environment "endorse" JAX-WS 2.2.

I tried placing a `jaxws-api.jar` in `%JAVA_HOME%\lib\endorsed` and I tried adding that jar to the project's libraries list but none seemed to help.

I am not using [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6947451/562776), so I can't even list it as a dependency and hope that this will be magically resolved.

Any idea how to solve this problem? So that I can make this very simple project build?

Comment: What version of Java are you using to build your samples?

Comment: The source code you mentioned builds just fine for me with Java 1.6, Ant 1.8.2, Mac OS X 10.7.5. Can you confirm your system stats, and that you have *not* modified the downloaded source project in any way?

Comment: @Perception The CXF version is more critical, as implied by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10448329/generating-web-service-proxy-classes-using-wsdl2java-apache-cxf#comment13919799_10448329

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From your description this sounds similar to the problem described [in this post](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2007/01/problems_using.html).

To get around this issue, You can simply copy `jaxb-api.jar`, `jaxws-api.jar` to JDK's JRE's
`/lib/endorsed`

**Note** that "endorsing" means placing the relevant JAR files (jaxb-api.jar, jaxws-api.jar in this case) in `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\endorsed` (note the `jre` in the path). Do **not** create the *endorsed* directory directly under the JDK's *lib* directory.

or... if you prefer not to touch your JDK install, use these env vars is using wsimport and wsgen (where JAXWS_HOME points to JAX-WS 2.1 installation):

```
WSIMPORT_OPTS=-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%JAXWS_HOME%/lib
WSGEN_OPTS=-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%JAXWS_HOME%/lib
```

or... If you use ant tasks, you can pass `-Djava.endorsed.dirs=%JAXWS_HOME%/lib` as jvmarg while calling wsimport and wsgen ant tasks (for this to work, you need to set fork="true" attribute of wsimport and wsgen ant tasks).

Credit goes to [Rama Pulavarthi](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ramapulavarthi/archive/2007/01/problems_using.html).

Comment: The `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib` (vs. what I did which was %JAVA_HOME%\lib) was it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Endorsing the 2.2 version of the jaxws-api jar should work.   You could also pass the "-fe jaxws21" flag to the CXF wsdl2java command to make it generate 2.1 compatible code instead.

Answer (score 0):

Adding *webservices-api-2.2.jar* alone in **%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\endorsed** has resolved issue for me.