# 'cannot find symbol' error during super call to javax.xml.ws.Service

Tags: java, build, jenkins, compilation, jax-ws

When using build script to compile jax-ws classes, compiliation errors were thrown complaining 'cannot find symbol' even though I included the correct jar in the classpath (jaxws-api.jar),  I printed out the classpath entries to make sure all depenedent classes are there. any further ideas?

```
[javac] symbol  : constructor Service(java.net.URL,javax.xml.namespace.QName,javax.xml.ws.WebServiceFeature[])
[javac] location: class javax.xml.ws.Service
[javac]         super(wsdlLocation, serviceName, features);
[javac]         ^
[javac] 3 errors
```

Comment: "cannot find symbol" means the compiler can't resolve some variable or name, etc. Please add the full stacktrace in your question

Comment: This error happens exclusively when I used jenkins to automate the build. By using ant only, it doesn't throw such error, unfortunatelly, jenkins doesn't provide full stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Just searched around and found something related in one [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131503/javac-cannot-find-symbol-constructor-service?rq=1). Will be trying the same and keep updated.